# Getting Newest Records from MySQL (7 days)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, intervals

I am trying to grab the newest records from my table. I want all of the records that happened in the past 7 days. Here is what I have so far to start with.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM mlg_logattempts AS a WHERE a.ts = (SELECT MAX(ts) FROM mlg_logattempts AS b WHERE b.ts > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE AND b.name = a.name)";
```

I have used intervals in the past but an unsure how to make this work now. Can someone show me the proper way to request the past 7 days records? I do have a timestamp field.

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately I realized the command I shared with you. I do not have any of the above fields. The only date field I have is "date". no a or ts.

Comment: something like `DATE_ADD(your_col, INTERVAL 7 DAY) <= NOW()`

Comment: @Class that didnt work :(

Comment: try: `DATE_SUB`. OR you might need to switch NOW() with your_col

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use mysql date_diff() for dates
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

but since you use timestamps, the interval is a good solution:

b.ts > unix_timestamp(CURDATE()-INTERVAL 7 DAY)

Comment: yeah I guess you have just removed the unix_timestamp part, correct? :)

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that the date of login attempt is b.ts and it's formatted like `2013-08-20 03:08`:

```
$past7days = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("-7day")); 
$query = "SELECT * FROM mlg_logattempts AS a WHERE a.ts = (SELECT MAX(ts) FROM mlg_logattempts AS b WHERE date >= '$past7days' AND b.name = a.name)";
```

Comment: Edited it. Try and let me know